# VisualSVN Option is not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I have Installed Visual Studio 2013 and then Installed VisualSVN-Server-2.7.8, But There is no Option for VisualSVN in Visual Studio .This Option can be seen in my Visual Studio 2012 as I Installed on another system ,Please help me how to integrate svn in visual studio 2013 manually.

Comment: are you using the latest installer of VisualSVN? It detects all versions of visual studio including 2013 that are installed in my machine.

Comment: VisualSVN **Server** is not the same as **VisualSVN**. Are you sure you installed the correct package?

Comment: @lassev.Karlsen thank you . I was installing VisualSVN Server mistakenly latest version ,Now I Installed VisualSVN Client and this worked for me all version of visual studio were detected .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual SVN Server is an SVN server. It bundles a pre-configured and customized version of Apache with SVN. It provides a really good experience hosting SVN on Windows with really quick and easy installation, updates, and maintenance.

For Visual Studio integration you want Visual SVN, not Visual SVN Server. You need at least Visual SVN 4.0.0 to support Visual Studio 2013. The latest release is 4.0.p.

http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/

Comment: @lassev.Karlsen thank you . I was installing VisualSVN "Server" mistakenly latest version ,Now I Installed VisualSVN "Client" and this worked for me all version of visual studio were detected .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2012. Uninstalled Microsoft GIT tools, and Visual SVN options became visible.